# Mongodb 2.0 nodejs driver : .find(), .count() and .find({raw:true}) return incompatible results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, count, find

I have a very strange issue:

My `.find()` method and `.count()` method do not return objects that are compatible, eg `.find()` returns no object at all, and `.count()` returns 1.

Here is my code (Coffeescript)

```
config = require('../config.js')
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/#{config.General.database}",(err,db)->

  callback=(err,hands)->
    if err then throw err
    console.log 'find:'+hands.length
    console.log hands

  callbackCount=(err,c)-> console.log 'count:'+c

  condition={"processed":null}

  db.collection('hands').count(condition,callbackCount)
  db.collection('hands').find(condition).toArray(callback)
  db.collection('hands').find(condition,{raw:true}).toArray(callback)
)
```

Here's a gist to the compiled JS: https://gist.github.com/74ab937bf7636d4bf9cf

This returns:

```
count:1
find:0
[]
find:1
[ <Buffer 35 0c 00 00 02 5f 69 64 00 0d 00 00 00 31 32 38 36 37 36 35 33 35 37 30 38 00 04 70 6c 61 79 65 72 73 00 b8 03 00 00 03 30 00 60 00 00 00 08 61 63 74 69 ...> ]
```

What is strange is that the find condition will not return the hand without any special options. However, if I set the option {raw:true}, the find method will give me back some results, which makes me think the raw conversion to data is not done correctly ?

My database consists of a huge amount of 'hands' (around 1.7 million), which are indexed with the `processed` flag.

When I run `db.hands.find()` and `db.hands.count()` in mongo command line, I get the expected result (eg the hand object, and 1).

If I roll back to version 1.4 of the nodejs mongo driver, find and count seem to work consistently.

I have also found out that if I insert another hand element, the `find` is working again.

I'm running mongod without any special options, and I am on a development machine.

Any ideas why this strange behavior ?

## Edit:

Restarting mongod didn't change anything.

It seems that the problem is quite difficult to reproduce, I have just inserted 2 million hands in a test database and I couldn't reproduce the issue that way.

Comment: Not seeing this on 2.0.13. How did you define in package JSON? As `"mongodb": "2.x"` or as something else?

Comment: like this : "mongodb": "~2.0.0", I will try to create a test database

Comment: This is driving me crazy. They doesn't  seem to be any difference between the test data I've added and my real world data. Though somehow, I am not able to reproduce the issue. Is it possible that some of the items are locked somehow ?

Comment: I have updated my question by adding the fact that if I use the `{raw:true}`, option, the hand is returned.

Comment: @edi9999 Is the index on `processed` a sparse index?

Comment: No I don't think so, I've not set the sparse option. Here is the result of db.hand.getIndexes:  `[{
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "processed" : true
                },
                "name" : "processed_true",
                "ns" : "berlin.hands"
        }]`

Comment: If you do manage to reproduce the issue, could you write a small script to show the repro and open a [Node driver ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE)?